# How to save text file using xamarin And where is file get saved

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, xamarin

I am new to Xamarin. I have simple app; Where I have notes field and take picture functionality. I am using media plugin to take pictures. The picture obviously get saved in phone gallery. 
But I also wanted to save the text file which contains the input from notes field in phone.

I am struggling to save the text file.

The is the product structure. I am using shared project.

[File structure and classes image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PTjKq.png)

[Sample app image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UWhj3.png)

I have an save button. What I want to do is when save button is clicked; save the text file which has user input from notes field.

**Here is action of my save button**

I was looking on this website 
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/app-fundamentals/files?tabs=windows

I tried some code but nothing worked.

```cs
private async void Take_Photo_Button_Clicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    await CrossMedia.Current.Initialize();
    if (!CrossMedia.Current.IsCameraAvailable || !CrossMedia.Current.IsTakePhotoSupported)
    {
        await DisplayAlert("No Camera", ":( No camera available.", "OK");
        return;
    }

    var file = await CrossMedia.Current.TakePhotoAsync(new Plugin.Media.Abstractions.StoreCameraMediaOptions
    {
        SaveToAlbum = true,
        Name = jobnoentry.Text + "-" + Applicationletterentry + "-" + signnoentry.Text + "-" + SignType,

    });


    if (file == null)
        return;

    MainImage.Source = ImageSource.FromStream(() =>
    {
        var stream = file.GetStream();
        return stream;
    });


    //Save text field 

    string fileName = Path.Combine(Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.LocalApplicationData), "temp.txt");
    File.WriteAllText(fileName, "Hello World");


}
```

Comment: "nothing worked" - what does this mean?  Did you get an exception or error?  How are you trying to verify that it did work?

Comment: I do not get any error message. And I look through all file folders in my emulator device to look for a file. Not sure what is the best way to verify actually.

Comment: use File.Exists or File.ReadAllText.

Comment: I believe File.ReadAllText(fileName) is going to read file. I want to save the file. That is why I went with File.WriteAllText(fileName, text);

Comment: Yes, that's exactly what it does.  You read the file after you write it to verify that it was written correctly.

Comment: I have added the readfile code after the write file. Nothing Happend. Not even sure that worked.

Comment: did you check that the data returned matched what you expected?  It will throw an exception if the file does not exist.

Comment: I checked in log and I had this line displaying.  " FileImageSourceHandler: Could not find image or image file was invalid: File:  ". Not sure why its not working. But i dont think this is to do with text file.

Comment: did you actually try what I suggested?

Answer (score 6):

First, where exactly a file gets saved depends on the platform, but you can always print the string for the filename to see the actual path, e.g.

```
string fileName = Path.Combine(Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.LocalApplicationData), "temp.txt");
Console.WriteLine(filename); // will write the actual path to the application output.
```

In any case the path you are using, `Environment.SpecialFolder.LocalApplicationData`, will save the text file to a location only accessible by the app itself, you won't see it in a file browser. If you need to have the text files available outside of your app, how to do that will vary based on platform and you will need to use a dependency service to get the correct file paths.

However you can verify if you have saved and can read a file as follows:

```
string fileName = Path.Combine(Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.LocalApplicationData), "temp.txt");
File.WriteAllText(fileName, "Hello World");
```

The above is code from your post. If you don't get an exception, chances are it worked. To verify:

```
var text = File.ReadAllText(filename);
if (text == "Hello World")
    Console.WriteLine("File contents verified and correct");
else
    Console.WriteLine("File contents do not match saved string");
```